# vim CursorLineNr inconsistency on different terminals

Tags: vim

My CursorLineNr is set by the colorscheme xoria256. When I do ssh to a different machine but having
same .vim/ directory (including colors, plugin) I get a different behavior.
As seen in screenshot Line number 9 is colored on only one terminal. I have tried different color schemes but ColorLineNr is set on only one terminal. Am I missing any configuration? Both machines have same .vimrc and .vim/* and support 256 color terminal.

Thanks...

[image]
[image]

Comment: What versions of vim are you running? (local and ssh)

Comment: But do they have the same Vim? What is the version, including patch-level?

Comment: one which shows colored CursorLineNr:% vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Nov 22 2012 14:53:26)
Included patches: 1-547 Other one:VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb 18 2013 13:17:01) Included patches: 1-524

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell `CursorLineNr` is not set within the xoria256 colorscheme.

Things to try. Updating vim so that both version are at the same patch level. There might be a bug somewhere that got fixed in the 23 patches (or CursorLineNr was added).

Try the following command in the vim that doesn't show the CursorLineNr and see if it turns on.

```
:hi CursorLineNr term=bold ctermfg=11 gui=bold guifg=Yellow
```

If it does go add it to xoria256 if you don't mind modifying it or add it to `.vim/after/colorscheme/xoria256.vim`